# finite geometric series has a known sum. does this imply anything about the halfway point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi: I have a question about a geometric series and it has nothing to do with complex analysis because the series is real-valued. But I know people who follow this tag are really talented and I have had tricky geometric series questions answered here in the past so I figured I would ask the question here. If I should ask it somewhere else, just let me know. My apologies in advance if it is not appropriate for this tag.

Question: Suppose I have the following sum where N can assumed to be even and $\rho$ is real.

A)$ ~~~~~~ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \rho^{i} = \frac{1-\rho^N}{1-\rho}$.

So, what above means is that the finite series ( somehow ) equals what the sum of the infinite series would be.

My question is the following: If the above is true, does this imply that
$\rho^ \left({\frac{N}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$.  In other words, if I know that the
finite sum is equal to what the infinite sum would be, then does that imply that $\rho$
raised to the index at the halfway point of the series equal 1/2 ?

This question probably sounds off the wall but I work in econometrics and it has relevance there. Thanks a lot for any insights. Oh, if the answer is yes, is there a way to prove it ?

Comment: The formula A) is wrong.

Comment: Formula A) cannot hold for $\rho \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In econometrics, the halflife of a geometric series is the time it takes for the initial term to become half of what it was initially. So, if I have a geometric series such as

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^i$

Then the half life of this series is defined as the index
of the term that it is equal to 1/2. So, it's easy enough to solve for it if $\rho$ is known. You just solve $\rho^{halflife} = 1/2$ so that $halflife = log(1/2)/log(\rho)$.

But my question was the following: Suppose, we know the halflife occurs at the fifteenth term say so that the halflife = 15.  Then, what does this say about the value of the thirtieth term in the series.  Well, it turns out that it's easy enough to solve for that. Since, we know that $p^{15} = 1/2$, this means that $\rho^{30} = \rho^{15}*\rho^{15}$ = (1/2)*(1/2). So, if the halflife of a series is 15, then this means that the 30th term will be $1/4$. ( and not approximately zero like I was thinking ).  I did not explain the question clearly so I hope this clarifies it. Thanks for your efforts. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\rho^i = \frac{1}{1-\rho} = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\rho^i$$.

Then you have

$$0= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\rho^i - \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\rho^i = \sum_{i=N}^{\infty}\rho^i =
\rho^N \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\rho^i = \frac{\rho^N}{1-\rho}$$

So this implies that $\rho = 0$

Comment: thanks but I should have mentioned that it's not going to hold exactly. Note thought that for small enough $\rho$ and\or large enough $N$, it can hold, albeit approximately. In econometrics, we're always dealing with approximations. My question is whether the approximation being true, then implies "symmetry" of what term is the finite sum is 1/2. In other words, will it always be the case that the term that is 1/2 always occurs in the middle of the sum ? Thanks and sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Honestly I cannot understand what do you mean. I think I cannot be helpful.

Comment: no problem  crostful. it turns out that I sort of solved my problem. I will write the answer in the answer your question section.